# Netlogo: How to build connections between turtles conditional on their variables being in the same list?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to build a network model in NetLogo. Each turtle has a generation `g` and she has a `child` who belongs to generation `g+1` and a parent who belongs to generation `g-1`. Each turtle has a variable called `parent` which is equal to `turtle who + N` , `N` is the number of turtles in a generation. So for example, if N = 10, turtle 5 is the parent of turtle 15 and turtle 3 is the parent of turtle 13.

I sorted the parent turtles according to their wealth level and divided this list into 10 sublist. In an N=20 example, the first sublist contains the poorest 2 parent turtle while the last one consists the richest two turtle. I want to build links between the two turtles who are in the same sublist and also between the children of these turtles. But there seems to be something wrong with my code. My code for connecting children is the following:

```
ask turtles with [generation = g] [
  foreach pdist [
    if member? parent ? [
      let new-links C - count my-links
        if new-links > 0[
        let candidates other turtles with [ (count my-links < C) and (generation = g) and (member? parent ?)]
        create-links-with n-of min (list new-links count candidates) candidates]]]]
```

And my code for connecting parents are:

```
ask turtles with [generation = g - 1] [
           foreach pdist [
             if member? turtle self ? [
               let new-links C - count my-links
               if new-links > 0[
                 let candidates other turtles with [ (count my-links < C) and (generation = g - 1) and (member? self ?)]
                 show candidates
                 create-links-with n-of min (list new-links count candidates) candidates]]]]
```

where `C` is the number of connections I'd ideally like to build, `pdist` is the lists of sublists i.e. agentsets containing parents with similar wealth levels.

I have no problem with creating `plist` and assigning parents to turtles correctly, if N = 20, each sublist contains 2 parents and each turtles have a `candidates` agentset containing one member. I don't know how to see that agent though. When I try `show candidates`, the output is like `(turtle 24): (agentset, 1 turtle)`. So my first question is how to see that 1 turtle. I guess this is where the mistake is. I suspect that `(member? parent ?)` might be wrong part. If so, could somebody please tell me how to correctly write this condition?

I am providing my whole code below if you would like to reproduce it and see the results. The only function related to the question is `update-links-with-seg`, you don't need to worry about the rest, and yes I am sure that the problem has nothing to do with the rest of the code :) . I'd really appreciate a lot if somebody could tell me what is wrong. This is my term paper and I am stuck here since days and my deadline is approaching. Many thanks in advance.

```
turtles-own
[
  wealth
  wage
  experience
  rank
  age
  offers
  generation
  bestoffer
  choiceset
  from_friends
  from_parent
  random_arrival
  child
  parent
  ]
globals [
  g
  r
  b
  al
  ah
  Nmax
  rmax
  wealth_dist
  sorted_parents
  con_break_prob
  pdist
  ]
to setup
  clear-all
  set rmax T
  set Nmax N
  set al 0.2
  set ah 0.8 
  set b 0.1
  set g 0
  set con_break_prob 1
  set wealth_dist []
  set sorted_parents[]
  set pdist []
  reset-ticks
  create-new-generation
  update-links-no-seg
end ;;to setup

to create-new-generation
  crt N
      [set wealth 0 set experience 0 set rank 0 set age 0 set generation g set xcor random 30 set ycor random 30 set color red]
 if g != 0 [
   ask turtles with [generation = g] [set parent turtle (who - N)] 
   ask turtles with [generation = g - 1] [set child turtle (who + N)]]
end

to update-links-no-seg
  ask links [if con_break_prob < random 1 [die]]
  ask turtles [
     let new-links C - count my-links
     if new-links > 0[
       let candidates other turtles with [ (count my-links < C) and (generation = [generation] of myself)]
       create-links-with n-of min (list new-links count candidates) candidates]]
end

to update-links-with-seg
   if g != 0 [
     set sorted_parents sort-on [wealth] turtles with [generation = g - 1]
     set pdist []
     let p 0
     while [p <= 9][
       let minlist (p * N) / 10
       let maxlist ((p + 1) * N) / 10
       let a sublist sorted_parents minlist maxlist
       show a
       set pdist lput a pdist
       set p p + 1]
     show pdist]
   if C > 0 [
     ifelse g = 0 
       [ask turtles with [generation = g][
       let new-links C - count my-links
       if new-links > 0[
         let candidates other turtles with [ (count my-links < C) and (generation = g)]
         create-links-with n-of min (list new-links count candidates) candidates]]]
       [ ask turtles with [generation = g] [
         foreach pdist [
           if member? parent ? [
             let new-links C - count my-links
             if new-links > 0[
               let candidates other turtles with [ (count my-links < C) and (generation = g) and (member? parent ?)]
               show candidates
               create-links-with n-of min (list new-links count candidates) candidates]]]]
         ask turtles with [generation = g - 1] [
           foreach pdist [
             if member? turtle self ? [
               let new-links C - count my-links
               if new-links > 0[
                 let candidates other turtles with [ (count my-links < C) and (generation = g - 1) and (member? self ?)]
                 show candidates
                 create-links-with n-of min (list new-links count candidates) candidates]]]]]
   ask links [show end1 show end2]]  
end

to go
  if stop-ticking? [stop]
  if any? turtles with [age = T] [
    set wealth_dist []
    let sorted_turtles sort-on [who] turtles with [age = T]
    foreach sorted_turtles [set wealth_dist lput [wealth] of ? wealth_dist]
    file-open "wealth.csv"
    file-print wealth_dist
    file-close
    ask turtles with [age = T] [die]]
  if any? turtles with [age = T / 2 ][
    set g g + 1
    create-new-generation]
  update-links-with-seg
  ask turtles [ set offers [0] set choiceset [0] set from_friends [0] set from_parent[0] set random_arrival [0]]
  set r 1
  while [r <= rmax] [
    ask turtles [
      ifelse r <= rank[
        if random-float 1 < ah [set offers lput r offers]]
        [if r <= experience + 1[
           if random-float 1  < al [
          set offers lput r offers]]]]
    set r r + 1]
  ask turtles with [age < T / 2] [pass-unwanted-offers-young]
  ask turtles with [age >= T / 2] [pass-unwanted-offers-old]
  apply-job-and-work
  ask turtles [if random-float 1 < b [set rank 0 set wage 0]]
  tick
end

to pass-unwanted-offers-young
  foreach offers [
    ifelse (? - 1 > experience) or (? <= rank)[
      if any? link-neighbors with [(? - 1 <= experience) and (? > rank)] [
        ask one-of link-neighbors with [(? - 1 <= experience) and (? > rank)][set from_friends lput ? from_friends]]]
    [set random_arrival lput ? random_arrival]]
end

to pass-unwanted-offers-old
  foreach offers [
    ifelse (? - 1 > experience) or (? <= rank) [
      ifelse (? - 1 <= [experience] of child) and (? > [rank] of child)
       [ask child [set from_parent lput ? from_parent]]
       [if any? link-neighbors with [(? - 1 <= experience) and (? > rank)] [
           ask one-of link-neighbors with [(? - 1 <= experience) and (? > rank)][set from_friends lput ? from_friends]]]]
      [set random_arrival lput ? random_arrival]]
end

 to apply-job-and-work
  ask turtles [ 
    ;if generation > 0[
      ;if is-turtle? parent[
        ;show [wealth] of parent
      ;show from_parent]]
    ;show random_arrival
    ;show from_friends
    set choiceset []
    foreach random_arrival[set choiceset lput ? choiceset]
    foreach from_parent[set choiceset lput ? choiceset]
    foreach from_friends[set choiceset lput ? choiceset]]
  set r 1
  while [r <= rmax] [
    let vacancies ((Nmax / rmax) * (1 + rmax - r)) - count turtles with [rank = r]
    let applicants count turtles with [member? r choiceset]
    ask n-of min(list vacancies applicants) turtles with [member? r choiceset] [set rank r]
    set r r + 1]
  ask turtles[
    set wage exp rank
    if rank > experience [set experience rank]
    set wealth wealth + wage
    set age (age + 1)]
end

to-report stop-ticking?
  ifelse g = 3 [report true] [report false]
```

Comment: You may want to make a reproducible toy model that produces the same error (see the info on [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))- your provided code does not run for me as-is.